# Is there a difference between using "over" or "across" to cross a river?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

> We had to use the bridge to go _______ the river.

What should be the preposition: *over* or *across*?

People are divided in their opinion. Some say *over,* while others say *across.* Some even say that it could be both. What is the correct answer?

Comment: Does the quote actually contain "over"? To add another "over" would be odd; even "across" doesn't really fit there -- the best answer is not to fill in the blank, I think.

Comment: @Robusto Rolled back as the author needs to answer the comment. It's not right to assume the answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: The assumption was yours. Your edit assumes what my edit completed. It's hardly believable that Abhinash is looking for a doubled preposition synonym there.

Comment: No the sentence doesn't contain 'over'. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: If you're going to Grandmother's house it would definitely be "over the river".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is it could be both. Unprompted, a native English-speaking reader would instantly comprehend the meaning, most likely without a hitch.

Personally, I wouldn't use either, but would simply use *cross*

> "We had to use a bridge to cross the river"

if the action concerned personal mobility, or *span*

> "We had to use a bridge to span the river"

if the action concerned the placement of a permanent crossing.

Note that *bridge* can be used as a verb as well, but mainly in a figurative sense these days:

> We were mostly successful in bridging the divide between good sense and good morals.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to getting from one bank of a river to the other the words "across" and "over" can be used interchangeably. An example of this interchangeability is one verse of the traditional song ["The Waters of Tyne"](https://lyricsplayground.com/alpha/songs/w/wateroftynethe.html) from North East England. This verse is:

> Oh where is the boatman, my bonny hinney
>
> Oh where is the boatman, go bring him to me
>
> For to ferry me **over** the Tyne to my honey
>
> Or scull him **across** that rough river to me.

This refers to crossing a river by boat in the absence of a bridge but both words are used in spite of the fact that the boat travels *through* the water rather than *over* it. Both words can be used almost regardless of the actual method of crossing.